# How to concatenate groups into a new string column in pandas?

Tags: pandas, group-by

I'm still pretty new to pandas, and can't quite wrap my head around this one.  I have a table that looks like this:

| Timestamp | Sport | Place |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10/1/2022 12:05:00 | basketball | place1 |
| 10/1/2022 4:05:00 | basketball | place1 |
| 10/2/2022 16:05 | basketball | place1 |
| 10/2/2022 9:00 | basketball | place2 |
| 10/2/2022 11:00 | football | place3 |
| 10/2/2022 11:15 | soccer | place1 |
| 10/3/2022 11:15 | baseball | place4 |
| 10/3/2022 11:20 | tennis | place5 |
| 10/3/2022 11:30 | tennis | place5 |

And I'd like to read have a python script that uses pandas to produce this:

| Date | Sport | Place |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1-Oct | 2x basketball | place1 |
| 2-Oct | 2x basketball, 1x soccer | place1 |
|  | 1x basketball | place2 |
|  | 1x football | place3 |
| 3-Oct | 1x baseball | place4 |
|  | 2x tennis | place5 |

I can't quite figure out how to do the groupby correctly and then to concatenate the columns.

(And i'm going to want to do this for many similar tables, so i want to use a script.)

This gets me very close:

```
val_cnts = df.groupby(['date', 'Place'])['Sport'].value_counts()
```

But this returns a multi-indexed series of just the sport counts, so it looks like I need to turn some of the indices into columns, and then do some concatenations.  When I do a .reset_index()  on the Place and Sport indices though, that still doesn't work because the groupings don't seem right anymore.

Comment: Why is on `1-Oct` `2x basketball, 1x soccer`? there's no soccer on that date in your input table.

Comment: @AndrejKesely That row should be 2-Oct.  Fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
df["Timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Timestamp"])
df["Date"] = df["Timestamp"].dt.strftime("%-d-%b")

df = (
    df.groupby(["Date", "Place"])["Sport"]
    .value_counts()
    .to_frame(name="x")
    .reset_index(level=2)
)
df["Sport"] = df["x"].astype(str) + "x " + df["Sport"]
df = df.groupby(level=[0, 1])["Sport"].agg(", ".join).reset_index()

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    Date   Place                     Sport
0  1-Oct  place1             2x basketball
1  2-Oct  place1  1x basketball, 1x soccer
2  2-Oct  place2             1x basketball
3  2-Oct  place3               1x football
4  3-Oct  place4               1x baseball
5  3-Oct  place5                 2x tennis
```